# DVI-I to VGA Adapter does not work?

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, gpu, vga, dvi

So I was trying to find a way to get dual monitor for a while now. I bought this https://www.lazada.com.ph/-i100246212-s100289910.html?urlFlag=true&mp=1.

Now I tried connecting my second monitor along with my main monitor but the second one does not seem to be detected. I tried connecting the second monitor using the adapter with my main unplugged but it still didn't work. Even updating the drivers didn't work.

Previously I have also tried inserting a weaker GPU to run along with my iGPU but I can't find the setting for running 2 GPU in my BIOS.

GPU: Integrated Radeon HD 8570D
Motherboard: http://www.emaxxtech.com/product/emx-a58fm2hd-icafe/

Comment: 1. How are the two monitors connected (one VGA, the other DVI)?  2. By "dual monitors", are you looking for different outputs or two copies of identical content?  3. The motherboard info looks like it's DVI-I,  The analog signal it carries is likely the same output as the VGA port, so you probably won't be able to get different VGA content.  4. That adapter looks passive; it probably just grabs the analog signal from the DVI-I port rather than actively converting the digital portion of the DVI signal to analog. 5. What inputs do your monitors have? (cont'd)

Comment: If at least one has a digital input (DVI or HDMI), you may be able to do dual monitors where one is digital and one analog.  You would go directly from VGA to VGA for one, and DVI output to DVI or via adapter to HDMI monitor input.  6. You can get active DVI to VGA adapters, but you might be better off putting that money into a monitor with a digital input.

Comment: 1. One VGA-VGA and the other is VGA to DVI-I. 2. 2 different output. Ughh I guess I'll just get a hdmi cable then since all my monitors are VGA and I have a TV right beside my PC. Thank you

Comment: It's entirely possible that the Integraded/Radeon HD 8570 combo  just has a single sets of RGB DACs, so it can drive *either* the VGA output, *or* the analog part of the DVI-I output, but not both. In that case you'd need to use a digital output. So yes, investing in a cheap HDMI cable is the simples solution.